# Appending objects to a global list in python

Tags: python, list, class, object

I am trying to get the user to make an object called a NoteSet, each NoteSet will be put into a global list called db. This is my attempt at making this:

```
import sys
import datetime
db = list()
class NoteSet:
    nextseqNum = 0
    def __init__(self,name,description,hidden):
        global db
        self.seqNum = Note.nextseqNum
        self.name        = name
        self.description = description
        self.dateCreated = datetime.date.today()
        self.hidden      = hidden
        self.notes       = list()
        db[self.seqNum]  = self
        print(self)
        print(len(db))
        Note.nextseqNum  += 1
```

When I try to create an object for example:

```
NoteSet('example','ex',True)
```

It gives me the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       NoteSet('example','ex',True)
>     File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\step5.py", line 22, in **init**
>       db[self.seqNum]  = self
>   IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Is this the right way to make a global list of objects?

Comment: why not have the list inside the class?

Comment: The user will be able to make as many note sets as they want so won't it have to go outside the class?

Comment: make it a class attribute like nextseqNum, what is Note?

Comment: Later I'm going to have to let the user search through the database and select a noteset, will this work if it is a class attribute? After the user selects a noteset they should be able to add a different object (a note) to the specific noteset that they selected.

Comment: Note is another object, a noteset will just be a list of notes attached to the noteset

Comment: all instances will use the db list so it will behave as your global list is if I understand what you are trying to do

Comment: BTW, almost all Python programmers use `[]` instead of `list()`.

Comment: Will I be able to access the db list from outside the class? for instance if I entered print(db) in my main function should that work?

Comment: True ^^ I know how I'll go about this now, thank you!

Comment: No worries, you could also use a dict and use `NoteSet.db[Note.nextseqNum] = self` where the keys are the sequence numbers

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `db` has no elements in it (python lists are initialized to length 0), so when you try and replace the element at location `self.seqNum`, you are acessing an invalid index. It has nothing to do with the global-ness of it.

If we assume that this global list is only ever going to be accessed in a thread-safe manner, you should simply be able to do:

```
db.appened(self)
```

Instead. However, as mentioned in the comments, it makes more sense in this use case to make `db` a class variable if this class is the 'gate keeper' to interfacing with the db list.

**UPDATE**

To address the OP's question in the comments,

> I am looking to be able to keep track of the location of the objects in the list by the seqNum

As currently written, `seqNum` will always increment linearly, forever, with each new `NoteSet` instance. If we assume thread-safe access of `Note.nextseqNum`, then what you're trying to do via `db[self.seqNum]` is already implicitly done via `db.append(self)`, because `len(db) == Note.nextseqNum`, always. For now, we're going to ignore what happens if you cand ***remove*** elements from `db`, because right now your system doesn't account for that at all and would completely break anyway.

If, however, in the future `seqNum` doesn't just increase monotonically forever each time you make a new instance, you can simply make `db` a `dict` instead of a `list`:

```
db = dict()
```

And then insert the new instance to it exactly as you are currently,

```
db[self.seqNum] = self
```

`db` now represents a *mapping* of a `seqNum` to a `NoteSet` explicitly, rather than an implicit relationship based on an array index.

I would actually recommend doing it this way anyway, as it will also solve the problem of removing items from `db` for 'free'. As is, doing `del db[instance.seqNum]` will completely invalidate all mappings of `seqNum` into `db` for any instance that came after the removed instance. But if `db` is a `dict`, then this operation does what you expect it to and all of the `seqNum` values still map to the correct instance in `db`.

So, to bring it all together, I would recommend you alter your class to look like the following:

```
import sys
import datetime

class NoteSet:
    nextseqNum = 0
    db         = dict()

    def __init__(self,name,description,hidden):
        self.seqNum      = NoteSet.nextseqNum
        self.name        = name
        self.description = description
        self.dateCreated = datetime.date.today()
        self.hidden      = hidden
        self.notes       = list()
        NoteSet.db[self.seqNum]  = self
        print(self)
        print(len(db))
        NoteSet.nextseqNum  += 1
```

Comment: I am looking to be able to keep track of the location of the objects in the list by the seqNum

Answer (score 0):

As @aruisdante said you will need to append to the list

Try this:

```
db = []

class ListObj:
    def __init__(self, name, msg, hide=False):
        self.name = name
        self.msg = msg
        self.hide = hide
        db.append(self)
```

Good Luck!